# Passing a Object to sql server Stored Procedure (as TVP)

Tags: object, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have scenario , where I pass the entity (Object) with other dependent child entity to the Stored procedure and the SP should create/delete/update the tables respective for that entity in the Database.

Eg - 
Entity - Person
ChildEntity - Skills, JobDetails.

so i will just pass the Person object which includes all the other object collection and the stored procedure will acccept that parameter and do the respecitve CRUD operation.

Is there any option where i can pass the whole object to DB and then play with the object in the DB.(I donot want to go with the XML approach also would like to pass the whole object instead of divinding the object into single entities)

Need your suggestions, Thanx.

Kind Regards